# Error in installing episerver community in cms

Tags: c#, episerver

I try to install episerver community in cms version 9.0 using 
*episerver visual studio extension*
then it shows "Already referencing a newer version of 'EPiServer.Framework'" and install it in cms version7.15 shows error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".Error log is:

> ERROR EPiServer.Framework.Initialization.InitializationEngine: Initialize action failed for Initialize on class EPiServer.Common.InitializationModule, EPiServer.Common.Framework.Impl, Version=7.5.446.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7

How to solve this problem?Does any one know this?

Thanks

Comment: Is 7.15 or 7.5 version you referring to? Exception is during runtime or install time?

Comment: CMS version in 7.15 and episerver.common version 7.5.The exception occured in the runtime.